# Add and remove element of vector at specific position

Tags: matlab, vector

Let `X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `Y = [1, 2, 1, 0, 1]` be vectors where `X` maps into `Y`. 
Now I want to identify the maximum and minimum of `Y`, which is easy: `[value_min, id_min] = min(Y) = [0, 4]` and `[value_max, id_max] = max(Y) = [2, 2]`.
Then I want to remove the element from `X` corresponding to the minimum in `Y` and expand evenly around the element in `X` corresponding to the maximum in `Y`, while keeping the number of points equal. For this example we remove  `X(4)=[]`. Then we expand like `X(2)=(X(2) - X(1))/2` and `X(3)=(X(3) - X(2))/2` such that `X` looks like `X = [1, 1.5, 2.5, 3, 5]`. How can I achieve this? I think there is a general pattwern.

### Solution

Now the following snipped should work for any vector of length `N`. Note that the first and final element are fixed.

```
[value_max, id_max] = max(Y(2:N-1));
X(id_max) = (X(id_max) - X(id_max-1))/2;
X(id_max+1) = (X(id_max+1) - X(id_max))/2;
[value_min, id_min] = min(Y(2:N-1));
X(id_min)=[];
```

Comment: Are we just talking about integers? Is X always monotonic increasing by 1? Does Y just contains 0, 1 and 2? Please give multiple examples.

Comment: No, infact we talking reals. X is monotic increasing though. Y may contain any values.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your problem but there are a few things you should take care of

```
% Any Vector should work
X=[1 2 3 4 5];
Y=[1 2 1 0 1];

%We dont need the actual min max
[~,MIN]=min(Y(2:end-1)); 
[~,MAX]=max(Y(2:end-1));
%you dont look at the first element so the index has to be increased by 1
MIN=MIN+1; 
MAX=MAX+1;

X(MIN)=[];%taking out the smallest element
Xnew= [X(1:MAX) X(MAX:end)]; %Extend the vector by taking the MAX value twice
%the mean for 2 elements is A+B/2
Xnew(MAX)=mean(Xnew(MAX-1:MAX)); %the left one and the element next to it
Xnew(MAX+1)=mean(Xnew(MAX+1:MAX+2)); %the right one and the element next ot it

%rewrite X and clear Xnew
X=Xnew;
clear Xnew;
```

- First of all this isnt very efficient, but if its just used to
  modify some vectors and not get called a million times a day it will
  do the trick.
- In your text you say remove the minima then stretch
  around the maxima, in your solution metacode it is the other way
  around. this will influence the outcome when min and max are next to
  each other, so please check which way you prefer.
- Y isnt changed in this at all so it cant be performed multiple times on the same vector.
- Is N (the length) of any importance later on? if not you can always just refer to "end"